# How to send 'Headers' in websocket python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, websocket

how can i make this

This is my code

```
import  websockets


async def test():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://iqoption.com') as websocket:
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)
# Client async code
```

The cuestion is , can i send this headers to get Authenticated in the server

Headers

```
    'Host':'iqoption.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0',
    'Accept' : '*/*',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Sec-WebSocket-Version' : '13',
'Origin' : 'https://iqoption.com',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'iExBWv1j6sC1uee2qD+QPQ==',
'Connection' : 'keep-alive, Upgrade',
'Upgrade': 'websocket'}
```

I could do it with this other code but the messages were still encrypted with tls

```
proxies = {"http": "http://127.0.0.1:8080", "https": "http://127.0.0.1:8080"}
urllib3.disable_warnings()

r = requests.get('https://iqoption.com/echo/websocket', stream=True,headers = Headers, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
#r = requests.get('https://iqoption.com/echo/websocket', stream=True,headers = Headers)
s = socket.fromfd(r.raw.fileno(), socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


def receive_and_print():
    #for message in iter(lambda: s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8", errors="replace"), ''):
    for message in iter(lambda: s.recv(1024).decode( errors="replace"), ''):
        print(":", message)
        print("")
import threading
background_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_and_print)
background_thread.daemon = True
background_thread.start()

while 1:
    s.send(input("Please enter your message: ").encode())
    print("Sent")
    print("")
```

Any advice??

Comment: How do these headers authenticate? There is no kind of authentication in there. And many of the headers (including Sec-WebSocket-Key) get already generated by the websockets library. Why do you even think that this is an Authentication problem?

Comment: With what libraries can I achieve that? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are currently missing a basic understanding of WebSockets as is shown on your previous experiments. WebSockets are not plain sockets. WebSockets are some socket-like think created after a HTTP handshake. You cannot just take the socket from the connection as you've tried after `requests` but you have to explicitly speak the WebSocket application protocol, defined in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

That said, using a library like `websockets` is much better. But you still have to use the actual WebSocket endpoint as target and not just some arbitrary URL on the same server. The endpoint in this case is not
`ws://iqoption.com` but  `wss://iqoption.com/echo/websocket`, i.e. a longer path and `wss://` instead of `ws://`.

Without the proper URL you get error messages you seem to interpret as authentication problems. But there is no authentication involved here at all. Once you use the proper endpoint it simply works without any need to send specific headers:

```
async def test():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://iqoption.com/echo/websocket") as websocket:
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)
```

Comment: Great, now everything starts to take shape. One more question .. Do I have to specify the port ("443") or does that not influence the result?

Comment: @newuser434: 443 is the default port for `wss://` and `https://`. As long as you use the default port you don't have to specify it explicitly but you can.

Comment: Yesssss  `wss://iqoption.com/echo/websocket:443`   This is the finall code¡ thx @Steffen Ullrich

Comment: @newuser434: Please make yourself familiar how a URL looks like and where the ports belongs. What you have is the wrong place for the port and it only works since this specific server ignores the extended path in the URL. See [Wikipedia:URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can directly add headers in the request. Here's my example using `websockets`.

```python
async def hello(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri=uri, extra_headers= {'Auth':'yourTokenHere'}) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(json.dumps({"action":"hello", "message":"hi"})) # AWS.APIGateway style for example
        message = await websocket.recv()
```

Btw, the way I figured out about the `extra_headers` is but directly checking the code [here](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/main/src/websockets/legacy/client.py#L399). And they do have a good documentation [here](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/client.html).

Comment: the link `https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/client.html` is broken