# Send headers in Websockets connection request from Python client

Tags: python, websocket, header

What is the correct method / syntax for adding headers to a websocket connection request using [Python Websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) ?

The server I'm trying to connect to requires headers in the connection request for authentication

```
async def connect():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://site.com/ws") as websocket:
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)

    # eg. does not work:
    async with websockets.connect(f"wss://site.com/ws, header={headers}") as websocket:
    async with websockets.connect(f"wss://site.com/ws, extra_headers:{headers}") as websocket:
```

Similar question was asked here but did not answer the core of the question: [How to send 'Headers' in websocket python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60308749/how-to-send-headers-in-websocket-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to documentation, you can pass headers in `extra_headers` param of `connect()` function. [Details here](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/asyncio/client.html).

So code should look something like this:

```py
async def connect():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://site.com/ws", extra_headers=headers) as websocket:
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)
```

Answer (score -2):

First create a websocket using `websockets.connect`.
Then send the JSON header in `websocket.send(header)`
And then start processing the responses.

This should work:

```
async def connect():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://site.com/ws") as websocket:
        await websocket.send(header)
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)
```